# TSC: TS2339 Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'

Tags: typescript

```
TS2339: Property 'useMockData' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.

15     global.useMockData = false;
```

I have inside an Express.js middleware:

```
  if (mockDataHeader) {
    global.useMockData = true;
    next();
  } else {
    global.useMockData = false;
    next();
  }
```

elsewhere in my project (`src/shared/definitions`)

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    useMockData: boolean
  }
}
```

After I added this file the lint error on the first code block went away. But during `ts-node run dev` TSC shows the error on lint. Does anyone know why this occurs?